# Setting flyout not hiding

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm using Setting flyout for showing About screen.

My problem is Setting flyout screen should be hide when I changed device orientation portrait to Landscape.

**Setting flyout screen hiding perfectly below case.**

1). Launch the application in Landscape mode. 
2). Open about screen thru Charm menu(Setting floyout)
3). Rotate device landscape to portrait.

**Setting flyout screen not hiding in below case.**

1). Launch the application in portrait mode. 
2). Open about screen thru Charm menu(Setting floyout)
3). Rotate device portrait to landscape.

The about screen setting flyout screen comes centre of the screen.

Is there any API's firing when changing the orientation portrait to Landscape?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Window.Current.SizeChanged` event. It's fired when device orientation is changed.

```csharp
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
        {
            //TODO:
        }
        else if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
        {
            //TODO:
        }
    };
}
```